# Go - How can I subtype a wrapped error class?

Tags: go, types

I am wrapping errors (to add context) and am afterwards distinguishing between two errors. This is a scenario that I am currently using for tests. (Did the function recognise the error correctly?) My question is how I can reduce the verbosity.

I have two functions that create different errors:

```golang
func a() error {
    return errors.New("a")
}

func b() error {
    return errors.New("b")
}
```

They are both called by a third function that propagates the erorr.

```golang
func doStuff() error {
    err := a()
    if err != nil {
        return WrapA{err}
    }
    err = b()
    if err != nil {
        return WrapB{err}
    }
    return nil
}
```

In my main function, I distinguish between both errors.

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    err := doStuff()
    
    switch err.(type) {
        case WrapA:
            fmt.Println("error from doing a")
        case WrapB: 
            fmt.Println("error from doing b")
        case nil:
            fmt.Println("nil")
        default:
            fmt.Println("unknown")
    }
}
```

So far, so good. Unfortunately, to implement `WrapA` and `WrapB`, I need a lot of code:

```golang
type WrapA struct {
    wrappedError error
}

func (e WrapA) Error() string {
    return e.wrappedError.Error()
}

func (e WrapA) Unwrap() error {
    return e.wrappedError
}

type WrapB struct {
    wrappedError error
}

func (e WrapB) Error() string {
    return e.wrappedError.Error()
}

func (e WrapB) Unwrap() error {
    return e.wrappedError
}
```

In other languages, I would create a single `Wrap` struct and let `WrapA` and `WrapB` inherit from `Wrap`. But I don't see a way to do this in Go.

Any ideas on how to reduce the clutter?

Go Playground https://play.golang.org/p/ApzHC_miNyV

EDIT:
After seeing jub0bs answer, I want to clarify:
Both `a()` and `b()` are callbacks I have no control over. They may return various errors. This is the reason why I wrap them.

Comment: There are no subtypes in go. There is no class hierarchy.

Comment: Sure, I was just wondering if I missed a more Go-esque approach to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can indeed simplify things:

- Define `a` and `b` as package-level `error` variables for ease and better performance.
- Unless you require programmatic access to values only accessible in the context of the error that you're wrapping, you most likely don't need to declare those custom `WrapA` and `WrapB` error types. Instead, you can simply use [the `%w` verb in conjunction with `fmt.Errorf`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Errorf) to produce a new error value that wraps the lower-level error.
- You can then use [`errors.Is`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is) within a tagless `switch` to inspect the cause of the higher-level error returned by your `doStuff` function.

([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rWUPzDBKlF0))

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

var (
    a = errors.New("a")
    b = errors.New("b")
)

func doStuff() error {
    err := a
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%w", err)
    }
    err = b
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%w", err)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    switch err := doStuff(); {
    case errors.Is(err, a):
        fmt.Println("error from doing a")
    case errors.Is(err, b):
        fmt.Println("error from doing b")
    case err == nil:
        fmt.Println("nil")
    default:
        fmt.Println("unknown")
    }
}
```

Comment: and here is the related code from the fmt package for anyone wondering https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.17:src/fmt/errors.go;l=32

Comment: This only works if (1) I can control how the errors are defined in a() and b(), and (2) both return just a single error. In my full use case, both conditions are not met. I will edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: @magum That wasn't clear from the original question; your edit changes things a bit. To clarify: what you want is determine whether the cause of the error returned by `doStuff` is function `a` or function `b`, correct? You're not so much interested in the nature of the underlying error, correct?

Comment: No, I definitely want to preserve the underlying error. That's why I am wrapping it. I am looking for a less verbose way to do exactly the same: (1) preserve the error information from `a()` or `b()`, (2) enrich the error with context `"error while calling a(): ..."`, and (3) match on the origin in main. 

The only other option I see to accomplish the same without wrapping, would be to match on the string prefix. So, something like `strings.HasPrefix(err.Error(), "error while calling a()")`. This does not look like a clean solution to me.

Comment: Just to be clear: The question has not changed with the edit. I am looking for a less verbose way to accomplish the same logic.

Comment: @magum Then I can't think of a way to reduce the verbosity of your approach `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Thanks for your attempt! Maybe there is simply no other way.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a structured error version which composes a type `Wrap` along various more specific error types;

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func a() error {
    return errors.New("something more specific broke in a")
}

func b() error {
    return errors.New("something more specific broke in b")
}

func doStuff() error {
    err := a()
    if err != nil {
        return ErrA{
            Wrap:        Wrap{err: err},
            SpecficProp: "whatever",
        }
    }
    err = b()
    if err != nil {
        return ErrB{
            Wrap:         Wrap{err: err},
            SpecficProp2: "whatever else",
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    err := doStuff()

    if target := (ErrA{}); errors.As(err, &target) {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", target)
    } else if target := (ErrB{}); errors.As(err, &target) {
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", target)
    } else if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("unknown")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("nil")
    }
}

type Wrap struct {
    err error
}

func (e Wrap) Error() string {
    return e.err.Error()
}

func (e Wrap) Unwrap() error {
    return e.err
}

type ErrA struct {
    Wrap
    SpecficProp interface{}
}

func (e ErrA) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("got error of kind A with %#v, plus %T", e.SpecficProp, e.Unwrap())
}

type ErrB struct {
    Wrap
    SpecficProp2 interface{}
}

func (e ErrB) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("got error of kind B with %#v, plus %T", e.SpecficProp2, e.Unwrap())
}
```

Comment: Here, ErrA and ErrB are not wrapped errors. So, if we later on cannot match on the contained errors. Otherwise, I like the idea. I tried to simplify it further here: https://play.golang.org/p/diIDlG-l1zC

Comment: avoid. If the caller is concurrent, you will have races. That s why i used the `if var decl; cond` declaration. But yes, those are not wrapped here, but using this pattern and `%w` verb of the fmt package, you can wrap any error.

Answer (score 0):

Use [constant errors](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/07/constant-errors) if you can. Then you could switch on the error itself.

Comment: I don't think constants work, when you want to wrap error messages.